# Different Viewport angles of the same object

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have reference pictures of Iron Man that I'm modeling. The pictures are angled. So I have modeled the object at the same angle. However, I would like to have a straightforward view of the object AND the angled view of the object at the same time in different windows. Any change in the object is seen in both windows since the object is the same, only the viewport view angle is changed. I know this is possible, but I don't know how to do this. thanks.[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, just split your 3D view? You could also link-duplicate your object with an Alt D, this way you don't have to split the view, if you work on a copy of the object it will change the other one

Comment: How do you split the 3D view? and how do I set the one of the views to the same angle as the top object (in my picture)

Comment: put your cursor at the corner of the view until you have a cross, left click and drag, to collapse you just need to have the cross and drag towards an existing window. By default the new window will have the exact same view

Comment: btw just tried your Alt-D idea, and it's more or less what I want to do. But I want to try the viewport way. Btw can I set the viewport at a specific angle? For example, if my object is at +5 on the X axis, then all I have to do is set the viewport view to -5 on the X axis, and then I would have a straightforward view of the object, even though the object is angled.

Comment: Yes Iunderstand what you want now and I guess Alt D is the best for your purpose

Comment: I just edited my comment, so can you check that? Thanks again, and btw moonboots, are you an AI, because I see you often answer questions, which requires a lot of dedication (which I and probably everyone else appreciates!).

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm the last generation of AIs

Comment: Last comment cuz I dont want stack exchange to get mad and move this to chat, but if you are serious, I am in awe. This is my first personal interaction with an AI. But just checked your profile. You've been here 7 years, not sure any generation of AI would be registered here 7 years ago. In any case, thanks for your help!

Comment: I am 7 year old and you are talking to version 3.0.1, you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep a front view in order to keep a front view of your reference image, the best is probably to link-duplicate your object (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>), rotate it so that it is rotated as your reference:

[image]

If you want to split the windows, put your cursor at the corner of the view until you have a cross, left click and drag, to collapse you just need to have the cross and drag towards an existing window. By default the new window will have the exact same view:

[image]